# Ordering by Time using cmp_to_key

Tags: python, sorting, time

I am trying to order my csvfile of food items by time whenever a new item is added. I have found a solution which I really like in which each time is compared against each other. My only issue is that I am unsure as to what variable/data structure I should place into the position marked with `times`.

What should happen is that the new row is added to the 2D list myRows, and then the contents of myRows is sorted based on time. The order should be earliest at the start, latest at the end.

```
    myRows = []
    with open("dataset.txt") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            myRows.append(row)
        newRow = [time, myType, desc, serving, kcal, sfat]
        myRows.append(newRow)
        myRows = sorted(times, key=cmp_to_key(compareTimes))
```

**Compare Times Function**

```
def compareTimes(timeStr1,timeStr2):
    #Convert the time Strings passed into function into time objects
    time1 = time.strptime(timeStr1, timeFormat)
    time2 = time.strptime(timeStr2, timeFormat)
    if time1 < time2:
        return -1
    elif time > time2:
        return 1
    else:
        #If times are the same
        return 0
```

**Dataset.txt**

```
22:30, Snack, Cereal, 200, 210,1.6
08:11, Breakfast, Cereal, 200, 210,1.6
08:20, Breakfast, Coffee, 200, 20,0.4
08:20, Breakfast, Pancake, 38, 74,1.4
10:30, Snack, Chocolate, 10, 56,2.5
```

I have tried `myRows[0]`,`myRows` etc however this has not worked.

Comment: `myRows = sorted(myRows, ...)` and `compareTimes` will get rows and you have to get times from rows in `def compareTimes(row1, row2)`

Comment: if you compare `22:30` with `08:11` then you don't have to convert it to `datetime` but use directly strings - see `print( "22:30" < "08:11" )`

Comment: @furas I have adjusted the function but now get this error ValueError: time data '08:20' does not match format '%I:&M&p'

Comment: why do you use `&` instead of `%`?

Comment: @furas Seems to be a typo in the book i'm reading , typical. Still I get the same error ValueError: time data '08:20' does not match format '%I:%M%p'

Comment: because you don't have element which could math to `%p` - (probably `AM`, `PM`). Try `'%H:%M'`

Comment: see table in documentation [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `myRows` as argument in `sorted()`

```
myRows = sorted(myRows ...)
```

But to sort strings like `22:30` with `08:11` you don't need function which convert strings to `datetime` because you can compare `"22:30" < "08:11"`. So you can use

```
myRows = sorted(myRows, key=lambda x:x[0])
```

---

```
text = '''22:30, Snack, Cereal, 200, 210,1.6
08:11, Breakfast, Cereal, 200, 210,1.6
08:20, Breakfast, Coffee, 200, 20,0.4
08:20, Breakfast, Pancake, 38, 74,1.4
10:30, Snack, Chocolate, 10, 56,2.5'''

import csv
import io

myRows = []
#with open("dataset.txt") as csvfile:
with io.StringIO(text) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        myRows.append(row)
    #newRow = [time, myType, desc, serving, kcal, sfat]
    #myRows.append(newRow)
    myRows = sorted(myRows, key=lambda x:x[0])

for row in myRows:
    print(row)
```

Result

```
['08:11', ' Breakfast', ' Cereal', ' 200', ' 210', '1.6']
['08:20', ' Breakfast', ' Coffee', ' 200', ' 20', '0.4']
['08:20', ' Breakfast', ' Pancake', ' 38', ' 74', '1.4']
['10:30', ' Snack', ' Chocolate', ' 10', ' 56', '2.5']
['22:30', ' Snack', ' Cereal', ' 200', ' 210', '1.6']
```

---

**EDIT:** The same with `pandas` is much shorter

```
text = '''22:30, Snack, Cereal, 200, 210,1.6
08:11, Breakfast, Cereal, 200, 210,1.6
08:20, Breakfast, Coffee, 200, 20,0.4
08:20, Breakfast, Pancake, 38, 74,1.4
10:30, Snack, Chocolate, 10, 56,2.5'''

import pandas as pd
import io

#myRows = pd.read_csv("dataset.txt", sep=', ', names=['time', 'myType', 'desc', 'serving', 'kcal', 'sfat'])

myRows = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=', ', names=['time', 'myType', 'desc', 'serving', 'kcal', 'sfat'])

myRows = myRows.sort_values('time')

print(myRows)
```

---

**EDIT:** version with function

```
text = '''22:30, Snack, Cereal, 200, 210,1.6
08:11, Breakfast, Cereal, 200, 210,1.6
08:20, Breakfast, Coffee, 200, 20,0.4
08:20, Breakfast, Pancake, 38, 74,1.4
10:30, Snack, Chocolate, 10, 56,2.5'''

import csv
from functools import cmp_to_key
import time
import io

def compare_times(row1, row2): # 'lower_case_names' for functions
    #time1 = time.strptime(row1[0], '%H:%M') # converting to time object
    #time2 = time.strptime(row2[0], '%H:%M') # converting to time object
    time1 = row1[0] # without converting to time object
    time2 = row2[0] # without converting to time object

    if time1 < time2:
        return -1
    elif time1 > time2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

myRows = []

#with open("dataset.txt") as csvfile:
with io.StringIO(text) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        myRows.append(row)
    #newRow = [time, myType, desc, serving, kcal, sfat]
    #myRows.append(newRow)
    myRows = sorted(myRows, key=cmp_to_key(compare_times))

for row in myRows:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but I did want to have that sort of Bubble Sort vibe by using the function. I am also not sure what key=lambda x:x[0] does. I almost have my version working however I seem to have the format wrong I have adjusted the function but now get this error ValueError: time data '08:20' does not match format '%I:&M&p'

Comment: functions send row to `key` and it uses function `lambda x:x[0]` to get value from first column to compare it. In your function you also will get rows and you have to get value from row to compare them.

Comment: I added version with `key=cmp_to_key(compare_times)`